# YouTube lightbox doesn't count view

Tags: view, youtube, count, lightbox, autoplay

I have a thumbnail.jpg hosted on my server, when clicked, open a jQuery lightbox and play YouTube video. However, by this method I need to add `&autoplay=1` in the embed code. Or else, users will need to click twice on the same video in order to play.

The problem is, [youtube said](http://gigaom.com/2008/07/23/youtube-says-autoplays-dont-count/) autoplay doesn't count the view. In my case, user DOES click on the thumbnail image hosted on my server. Is there any suggestion to use the same flow (click –> lightbox) and make YouTube count the view? This video is on top of the sidebar at my [website](http://www.dektalent.com/course-math-grade-talent-4.php).

Comment: I have this same exact issue, I'll let you know if I find a solution.